# Android How can I do an onclick from a baseadapter literally can not figure it out

Tags: android, listview, onclick, baseadapter

I have a listview  which is tied to a baseadapter which implements a custom adapter. I get data from the database so every Textview in the listview row has a different value when user click on that textview I want to show the value in a Toast.

This is my customAdadapter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:text="# votes"
        android:id="@+id/votes" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my base adapter

```
public class LocalFeed_CustomView extends BaseAdapter {

    JSONObject names;
    Context ctx;
    LayoutInflater myiflater;



    public LocalFeed_CustomView(JSONObject arr,Context c) {
        ctx = c;
        names = arr;
        myiflater = (LayoutInflater)c.getSystemService(c.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        try {
            JSONArray jaLocalstreams = names.getJSONArray("localstreams");

            return jaLocalstreams.length();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(ctx,"Error: Please try again",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return names.length();
        }


    }




    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;
        final CompleteListViewHolder viewHolder;
        try {
           if(convertView==null) {
                LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = li.inflate(R.layout.customadapter, null);
                viewHolder = new CompleteListViewHolder(v);
                v.setTag(viewHolder);

            }

            else {
                viewHolder = (CompleteListViewHolder) v.getTag();


            }


            JSONArray jaLocalstreams = names.getJSONArray("localstreams");
            final JSONObject jsonObject = jaLocalstreams.getJSONObject(position);


            viewHolder.votes.setText(jsonObject.getString("votes")+ " Votes");
            viewHolder.idnumber.setText(jsonObject.getInt("id"));


            viewHolder.votes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    LocalFeed dd= new LocalFeed();
                    String vote_id= String.valueOf(viewHolder.idnumber.getText());
  // this toast does not fire
                    Toast.makeText(ctx,"hello"+ vote_id,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });



            return v;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return v;


    }
}
class CompleteListViewHolder {
    public TextView votes,idnumber;

    public CompleteListViewHolder(View base) {

        votes=(TextView)base.findViewById(R.id.votes);
       idnumber=(TextView)base.findViewById(R.id.idnumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: What problem are you having besides `viewHolder.id` looks like it should be `viewHolder.idnumber`?

Comment: it is probably a NPE @codeMagic. `customAdadapter.xml` contains only **one** widget

Comment: I just edited that area out, my main issue is on viewHolder.votes when I click on the Textview that onClick event is not firing off

Comment: Hey @Blackbelt that xml file and the baseadapter contain more widgets but I did not include them in the example above because it would make the code more messier and it does not interact with the onclick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please assigned the views to the run time identifier in viewholder as show below

change

```
 if(convertView==null) {
                LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = li.inflate(R.layout.customadapter, null);
                viewHolder = new CompleteListViewHolder(v);
                v.setTag(viewHolder);

            }
```

to

```
 if(convertView==null) {
                LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = li.inflate(R.layout.customadapter, null);
                viewHolder = new CompleteListViewHolder(v);
                viewholder.votes = v.findViewById(R.id.votes);
                viewholder.idnumber = v.findViewById(R.id.idnumber);
                v.setTag(viewHolder);

            }
```

Also make you sure alignment of TextView along with padding and margin is proper, so that it can capture touch event properly